# App crashes when AdMob interstitial begins

Tags: ios, swift, admob, app-store, interstitial

I've recently uploaded my application to App Store but I've found an error. My program crashes every time an interstitial (AdMob) begins and I've no idea why. It never crashes when I run the program from Xcode..

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

First I've imported this one of course.

Also added this to my class

```
GADInterstitialDelegate
```

Inside the viewDidLoad() I've added this one:

```
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "AD-UNIT-ID")
    let request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID] //Should this be removed now when the app is on App Store?
    interstitial.load(request)

    interstitial.delegate = self
```

Further down I've added this code to my save-button:

```
                           //Advertisement test
                                if self.interstitial.isReady
                                {
                                    self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    print("Advertisement is not ready!")

                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
                                }
```

And for the last I've this:

```
    //Advertisement will dismiss from the screen
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial)
{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "History", sender: self)
}
```

How can I fix this problem? It crashes every time I press on that "Save button" and the screen is turning black and then boom, crashes.

So it never crashed before when I ran it from my Xcode project, but when I was in TestFlight and in App Store it crashes every time!